# What version of Git do I have?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git and I'm getting some errors. Research tells me I ought to update to the latest version. In the Windows installer, it says I have version 2.20.1 installed. But if I run

```
Git version
```

in the command line, it tells me I have version 1.9.4.msysgit.2. Does anyone know what this means? I've uninstalled and reinstalled twice and the inconsistency persists, and also my errors (another issue).

Comment: With `git --version` you can easily check the version. Type `git` in bash terminal for recheck does it really removed or not.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple versions of git installed? Did you search for git.exe on your PC?

Comment: It's possible you have more than one version installed.  Check your `PATH` to see if there is another copy floating around.

Comment: It appears that git version is the same as git --version. Same result. @pjs when you say check path is this something I do on the command line?

Comment: There are multiple ways to check.  Easiest is to type `path` at the command line, but you can also check the environment variable settings.  You'll see a list of directories that Windows uses to find executables.  The order of the directories is the order in which they get searched.  You can also do an explicit search for `git.exe`, as suggested by @WernerHenze, to see if there are multiple copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CMD session, type

```
where git
```

That will give you the PATH where `git.exe` is found.

Then type:

```
set PATH
```

That will show you the PATH currently used: your old git path is probably set *before* the new one you are trying to install.
Edit your environment variable ([as seen here](https://superuser.com/a/949577/141)) to modify your `PATH` and set the proper folder first (the one with the new Git).

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the details. The older version of git was in railsinstaller, which I did formerly. I uninstalled that and now the versions match.